# How to sort an array of objects based on two properties of the object

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

I have an array of objects like this for example.

```
names = [{firstName: "Rachel", lastName: "Green"}, {firstName: "Monica", lastName: "Geller"},
        {firstName: "Ross", lastName: "Geller"}, {firstName: "Phoebe", lastName: "Buffay"}]
```

I want to sort the array `firstName` and if the `firstName` is same then sort the bunch of objects with same `firstName` by the `lastName`.
Like it is done in MYSQL while we give `ORDER BY` keyword in query, but I want to do it in javascript in an optimal manner, any suggestions?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort is likely to be useful

Comment: @ChrisG, no. boolean values do not have negative values. take an other approach instead.

Comment: @NinaScholz I should've added that my "general" sort function is for string values only, yes.

Comment: @ChrisG, no please have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24080785/sorting-in-javascript-shouldnt-returning-a-boolean-be-enough-for-a-comparison

Comment: @SejalNaik what you have tried so far?